# Can inverted index have multiple words in one entry?

Tags: information-retrieval, stemming, inverted-index

In information retrieval, the inverted index has entries which are the words of corpus, and each word has a posting list which is the list of documents it appears in.

If stemming is applied, index entry would be a stem, so multiple words may finally map to the same entry if they share the same stem. For example:

Without stemming:

```
(slowing) --> [D1, D5, D9,...]

(slower) --> [D9, D10, D20,...]

(slow) --> [D2,...]
```

With stemming:

```
(slow) --> [D1, D2, D5, D9, , D10, D20...]
```

I want to avoid stemming, and instead would like to make each entry in my inverted index as a bag of words (inflections) such as (slow, slows, slowing, slowed, slower, slowest). For example:

```
(slow, slows, slowing, slowed, slower, slowest) --> [D1, D2, D5, D9, , D10, D20...]
```

Would that be possible and feasible or not?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about programming, but rather about data science/natural language processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer:**
Simply avoid stemming to suit your need of not considering `slow` and `slows` to be a match.

**Long Answer:**

Question: 
`I want to avoid stemming, and instead would like to make each entry in my inverted index as a bag of words (inflections) such as (slow, slows, slowing, slowed, slower, slowest).`

Let me try to clear some confusion that you have about inverted lists. It is the **documents** that are stored in the postings for each term (not the terms themselves).

The words are typically stored in a in-memory dictionary (implemented with a hash-table or a trie) containing pointers to the postings (list of documents which contain that particular term) stored and loaded on the fly from secondary storage.

A simple example (without showing document weights):

`(information) --> [D1, D5, D9,...]
(informative) --> [D9, D10, D20,...]
(retrieval) --> [D1, D9, D17,...]
..`

So, if you don't want to apply stemming, that's fine... In fact, the above example shows an **unstemmed** index, where the words `information` and `informative` appear in their non-conflated forms. In a conflated term index (with a stemmer or a lemmatizer), you would substitute the different forms with an equivalent representation (say `inform`). In that case, the index will be:

`(inform) --> [D1, D5, D9, D10, D20...]. --- union of the different forms
(retrieval) --> [D1, D9, D17,...]
..`

So, this conflated representation matches all possible forms of the word `information`, e.g. `informative`, `informational` etc.

**Longer Answer**

Now let's say you want to achieve the best of both worlds, i.e. a representation which allows this conflation to be done in a user controlled way, e.g. `wrapping a word around quotes to denote requiring an exact match (`"slow"`vs.`slow`in the query), or some indicator to include synonyms for a query term for semantic search (e.g.`syn(slow)` to include synonyms of the word slow).

For this, you need to maintain separate postings for the non-conflated words and maintain additional `equivalence indicating pointers` between a set of `equivalent (stem relation/synonym relation/ semantic relation etc.)` terms.

Coming back to our example, you would have something like:

```
(E1)-->(information) --> [D1, D5, D9,...]
 |---->(informative) --> [D9, D10, D20,...]
 |---->(data) --> [D20, D23, D25,...]


(E2)-->(retrieval) --> [D1, D9, D17,...]
 |---->(search) --> [D20, D30, D31,...]

..
```

Here, I have shown two examples of equivalence classes (concept representations) of two sets of terms `information, data...` and `retrieval, search...`.
Depending on the query syntax, it would then be possible at the retrieval time to facilitate exact search or relaxed search (based on inflections/synonyms etc.)

Comment: I know that posting list is a list of documents. Terms or words are the entries. I edited my question using your example to make it clearer. Thanks for the answer, I think it is not very different from what I meant. Would you please review my edited question ?

Comment: yes ur question is correct... if u found my answer useful, please upvote it...

Comment: The difference between my question and your answer is that I will add inflections that may not appear in the corpus.

Comment: ok... this is also admissible because it's also a common practice to employ a thesaurus to include out-of-vocab words and treat them as equivalent to a postings entry... e.g. u might have the word 'nuclear' in your corpus (and hence a postings for it)... all u need to do then is to point an external word, say 'atomic', to this entry... thus making them equivalent